# Is it possible to place all the items in grid in one row when I don't know the number of columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid container that has undefined number of columns and I want it to be one row. Is there any way to do this in CSS?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.grid > div {
  background: #ccc; 
  min-height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: grid-auto-flow:column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways actually.

1. Using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr));`. Fits new columns automatically and determines it's mimimum and maximum width. More about [Grid Template Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) and [auto-fit/auto-fill](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/).
2. Using `grid-auto-flow: column;`. Determines automatically placement behavior of grid cells. More about [Grid auto flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow).

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid > div, .grid2 > div {
  background: #ccc; 
  min-height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="grid2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```